# Изменить курсор при перетаскивание drag html

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно изменить курсор, когда элемент перетаскивается и находиться над элементом, в который можно поместить перетаскиваемый элемент?

В mac os данный курсор называется copy.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var elem = document.getElementById(data);
  ev.target.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```css
.drop {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.drag {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  cursor: move!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="drag_elem" class="drag" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event);"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, вставить `ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";`

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var elem = document.getElementById(data);
  ev.target.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```css
.drop {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.drag {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  cursor: move!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="drag_elem" class="drag" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event);"></div>
```

Comment: Подскажите, можно ли сделать что бы курсор был move, сейчас когда красный элемент находиться над синим курсор стандартный.

Comment: [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119514/html5-drag-drop-change-icon-cursor-while-dragging) отвечали на вопрос на английском SO. Есть рабочий [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/rvRhM/1/)

Comment: Правда костыль на маке работает через раз. Попробую ещё кое что

Comment: Было бы отлично

Comment: А этот DnD должен работать между несколькими окнами или в рамках одного окна? Если в рамках одного окна, то я бы рекомендовал обойтись без DnD простым перетягиванием. Так как похоже, что за некоторые  пропуски смены курсора виновата сама система макос.